# Error in making/building mupdf on Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, osx-mavericks, mupdf

I simply using the `make` command to make/build the mupdf on Mac OS X Mavericks, from its source.

But I get this error:

`fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found`

However X11 is installed on my Mac, and has an entry in the PATH environment variable as well.

Can anyone please help on how to get rid of this error and make/build MuPDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have **[MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php)** installed? If not, do so.

Then run:

```
sudo port -pf install xorg-libX11
```

This should install (amongst other files) `/opt/local/include/X11/Xlib.h`.

Comment: I instead build it on Windows, removed everything on MAC. I am gonna mark your answer correct as you atleast replied!