# Error when making muPdf on OS X Yosemite

Tags: android, osx-yosemite, mupdf

I get this error when trying to make muPdf on OS X Yosemite

> fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

I trying this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774396/error-in-making-building-mupdf-on-mac-os-x), without any effect...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I removed a typo in your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. Just install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/)